# Why doesn't MySQL installation on an Ubuntu linux 16.04 OS require user to specify LD_LIBRARY

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Why doesn't MySQL installation on ubuntu 16.04's linux require the user to specify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to resolve its runtime dependencies?

I tried googling to find the answer to this question, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The expert @roaima says, "Because MySQL is a packaged application that stores its libraries in one of the "well known places".